# Re-installed windows 7 and want my old wallpaper

Tags: windows-7

Ok, so I re-installed windows 7 yesterday and all is good. The only problem I have is that I had a really nice wallpaper before that I spent like 2 hours making, I set it as the wallpaper on my old installation but then later it got accidentally deleted.
Is there anyway I can find the wallpaper? I still have my windows.old directory with all my old user files.
Could I either find it somewhere in there or possibly access my old recycle bin?

**Edit:** I've just remembered that I did actually save it as a theme too, is that of any help? Anyone know where the themes are saved?

**Edit 2:** I found where the themes are and I can restore all of them and the wallpapers work but with the specific one I'm looking for the wallpaper doesn't work as the file was deleted -_-

Comment: Try in your windows.old\Web\Wallpaper

Comment: I can try to answer your question but can you please provide more information? Is the wallpaper you're looking for set as the wallpaper in the old windows installation? Because it's possible for a file to be set as a wallpaper then deleted. It would still be the wallpaper because windows keeps a copy of it.

Comment: Yes it was set when I re-installed - sorry I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Ofiris - Thats only the default wallpapers, im looking for one I made myself and had saved to my desktop before re-installing windows

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that C: is the old installation drive, try looking in following path

`C:\Users\username\AppData\Microsoft\Windows Photo Viewer\`

Non-Windows wallpapers are usually stored in this directory.

Replace **username** with the user-account name from the old installation.

Comment: First of all i thonk you forgot to add inn the "roaming" directory and second of all, after trying that I only found an old wallpaper that I used a long time ago.

Comment: Doesn't that just show the wallpapers you set from internet explorer? This is one I made in Photoshop and saved to my desktop, then set it as wallpaper and deleted it.

Answer (score 1):

this is the path where windows 7 is storing the wallpaper
C:\Users\user.old\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes

user.old is the old or defective user profile (account)

Answer (score -1):

[Look for `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`.](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2015/01/08#wallpaper-registry) On Windows 7, when you pick an image to use for wallpaper, it will be copied to the location specified as the value for `Wallpaper` in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`. The image will be renamed `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`, which you will find in that location, where *username* is the name for the relevant account. If that isn't the version of the wallpaper that you need, then you may still be able to recover the old version, since Windows 7 supports [Volume Snapshot Service (VSS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy). Even if you didn't make a backup copy of the file, Windows may have stored one for you. Right-click on that file name, i.e., `TranscodedWallpaper.jpg`, then choose **Properties**, then click on the **Previous Versions** tab. Hopefully, you will see something similar to the following:

[image]

If you see a previous version that you think may be the one you need, select it and click on **Restore**.

Note: It doesn't matter whether your original file was in another file format, such as .png. E.g., if you used mywallpaper.png, Windows 7 would copy it to that location as TranscodedWallpaper.jpg. Also, after restoring the file, Windows won't automatically update the wallpaper it displays. You will need to manually select the restored file to be the displayed wallpaper to have it appear as your wallpaper.

Comment: Why does your url point to a blog post into of a .jpg?

Comment: @Ramhound, if he created his own wallpaper, user1821586 may find it stored as TranscodedWallpaper.jpg or a prior version of that file, even if he doesn't have the original file he created, since Microsoft Windows will  copy the file substituting that name for the name he may have given the file.